# Attributes of a class are stored in?

Tags: c#

Are they stored in class methods or instanced methods? Or is it both? I am really looking for an explanation, and after much research I couldn't come to a definite answer.

Thanks

Comment: They are stored in the metadata. IIRC it is explained in the CLI standard. It's actually a .NET thing and not specific to C#

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Going for precision here, all the [attributes] used in an assembly are gathered together by the compiler and written to the metadata of the assembly.  Two tables in the metadata play are role.

The first one is the CustomAttribute table, it contains a list of every single attribute.  The list entry has an index to the original declaration that had the attribute (1), a reference to the constructor for the attribute type (2) and an index for the value that's used to construct the attribute object at runtime (3).

The second one is the Blob table, the value index (3) in the CustomAttribute table indexes it.  It contains the values you used in the attribute declaration.  Those values are a string if you used a string or typeof argument, the actual value if you used a value type value argument, an array of those values if you use an array.

Constructing the attribute object at runtime thus involves first finding the entry in the CustomAttribute array by (1).  Then locating the constructor for the attribute class by using (2) and jit compiling it if necessary.  (3) is used to lookup the entry in the blob table, converting the values in the blob as necessary, like retrieving the Type from the string, creating the array, etcetera.  And calling the constructor to create the object.

Organizing it that way has the big advantage that a declaration can have an arbitrary number of attributes and that attributes can be used on many kinds of declarations (assembly, type, method, parameter, field, etc).  The disadvantage is that finding them back isn't particularly cheap.

Comment: +1 Superb explanation Sir.! This surely should be accepted as an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Class attributes are stored in the `Type` object associated with the class.

```
Object x;
System.Reflection.TypeAttributes attributes = x.GetType().Attributes;
```

So the answer to your question is: really in neither of those as they are not part of the class as such.

Check more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.attributes.aspx

Comment: Thank You for your help and the link. I am about to fully read it to get a better grasp. I haven't had much sleep, and obviously I seem to be over complicating things. I would upvote, but I have less than 15 rep =[. Sot to sum is up Attributes are stored in class members?

Comment: They're stored in another object (of `Type` type) which, as MSDN says, `The Type object exposes the metadata associated with the class of the current Object`

Comment: This answer is quite misleading, it cannot easily explain how a method argument could have an attribute for example.  Attributes are not stored in the Type object, ParameterInfo has no relationship to the Type class.

Comment: @HansPassant Right, my answer is only true for class attributes, I modified it. And yes, your answer is better, +1 to it.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by  knittl in the comments(which is correct) you may check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcd8txaw.aspx):

> **The .NET Framework lets you declare specific kinds of metadata, called
>   attributes**, in your compiled file. Attributes can be found throughout
>   the .NET Framework and are used to control in more detail how your
>   program behaves at run time. Additionally, you can emit your own
>   custom metadata into .NET Framework files through user-defined custom
>   attributes. For more information, see Extending Metadata Using
>   Attributes.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa569283.aspx)*(CLI Partition II - Metadata and File Format ( word/pdf zip))*:-

> Attributes of types and their members attach descriptive information
>   to their definition. The most common attributes are predefined and
>   have a specific encoding in the metadata associated with them (§23).
>   In addition, the metadata provides a way of attaching user-defined
>   attributes to metadata, using several different encodings.

From [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct.aspx)

> You can use the members of the Type class to get the individual
>   methods and members in the passed class. This example first queries
>   the Type object to get attribute information for the class level.
>   Next, it uses Type.GetMethods to place instances of all methods into
>   an array of System.Reflection.MemberInfo objects to retrieve attribute
>   information for the method level. You can also use the
>   Type.GetProperties method to check for attributes on the property
>   level or Type.GetConstructors to check for attributes on the
>   constructor level.

Answer (score 1):

In short, they're stored in `IL`, this is an example of `[Serializable]` attribute in `IL`, seen using [IL Disassembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx).
[image]