# Marshaling IEnumVARIANT: reference to CustomMarshalers.dll in blob?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, marshalling, com-interop

Suppose I have the following C# code that accepts a COM object with IEnumVARIANT interface:

```
public void EnumeratorParameter( 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, 
     MarshalTypeRef = typeof(EnumeratorToEnumVariantMarshaler))] 
    IEnumerator enumerator) { }
```

To marshal it, I need to add a reference to CustomMarshalers.dll library. However, unlike with `mscorlib.dll`, this library is referenced not in with `AssemblyRef` metadata table but in blob heap via `FieldMarshal` table. Why the reference via blob is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the reference appears in an [attribute].  The attribute data that's used when the attribute class is instantiated is stored in the blob table.  More about that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19345013/17034).